# Copying files between servers SQL Job

Tags: sql-server-2008, jobs, xcopy

I have a SQL job that I would like to copy files in a directory out to a directory on another server. Here is the CMD that I am running

xcopy \DB1\TEST*.* \DB2\foo /S /Y

And I get this error
Executed as user: DOMAIN\SA$. File not found - *.*  0 File(s) copied.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.

I have also tried the copying to the same server with same results as well as just trying to grab one file and copying

I have added the DOMAIN\SA account as an admin on the servers and still getting this. Is this just a bug or am I missing some permissions setting?

Comment: Did you try using the full path?

Comment: MaximR yes with the same results